# Book with walrus-like aliens invading and using asteroids to wipe out major cities

Tags: story-identification, alien-invasion

I remember years ago reading part of a book that was reminiscent of [Footfall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footfall) but I can't remember the name or too much about it.

Some facts that stick out were the invading aliens were described as being like walruses, New Orleans and other major cities had been hit by asteroids and its mentioned that Japan surrendered immediately to the invaders while America still has military resistance in the Rocky Mountains.  I think it was a Baen published book.

Comment: See OP confirmation comment on answer below; OP indicates that duplicate target (the first book in the series) was what he was after, even though answer describes the sequel.

Answer (score 9):

This is "[The Crucible of Empire](http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/A1439133387/A1439133387.htm?blurb)" by Eric Flint.

The [book](http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/A1439133387/A1439133387.htm?blurb) opens in the Rocky Mountains after an invasion (by aliens with tusks).

> Conquered by the Jao twenty years ago, the Earth is shackled under
>   alien tyranny - and threatened by the even more dangerous Ekhat, one
>   of whose genocidal extermination fleets is coming to the solar system.
>   The only chance for human survival is in the hands of an unusual pair
>   of allies: a young Jao prince, newly arrived to Terra to assume his
>   duties, and a young human woman brought up amongst the Jao occupiers.
>   But, as their tentative alliance takes shape, they are under pressure
>   from all sides. A cruel Jao viceroy on one side, determined to drown
>   all opposition in blood; a reckless human resistance on the other,
>   which is perfectly prepared to shed it. Added to the mix is the fact
>   that only by adopting some portions of human technology and using
>   human sepoy troops can the haughty Jao hope to defeat the oncoming
>   Ekhat attack - and then only by fighting the battle within the sun
>   itself

As you've mentioned in your comment below, the book was preceded by "[The Course of Empire](http://www.baenebooks.com/10.1125/Baen/0743471547/0743471547.htm?blurb)",

[image]

Comment: Correction, thats the sequel.  The first book is what I am thinking of which was [The Course of Empire](http://www.baenebooks.com/p-88-the-course-of-empire.aspx).  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @john - We aim to please; http://24.media.tumblr.com/5fe1a5e8d665bdb7094a577eecdb4978/tumblr_n33dygnrcF1sk4l2mo1_500.gif

Comment: @JohnSmith - Don't forget to mark this as "accepted" to show that it was the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be "[Midnight At the Well of Souls](http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/0743435222/0743435222__c_.htm)" by Jack L. Chalker?

The aliens are described as being like "*Walrus-snakes*".

> They could see a giant figure coming toward them, and all stepped back
>   to the rear edge of the platform. As the figure came closer, they
>   could see that it was like nothing in the known universe: a human
>   torso, incredibly broad, an oval-shaped head with a huge white walrus
>   mustache, six arms spaced in rows down the torso, and the torso
>   melding into a huge serpentine lower half five or more meters in
>   length.

Comment: I don't believe that is the book.  The aliens were not described as being snake like and the setting was slightly after the completion of the invasion in the modern era.